# Trouble with Luna SA hsm + IIS

Tags: iis, hsm

I have Luna SA hsm and windows server 2012r2 + IIS, I'd like to lunch site using https, I'm performed standard connection operations between LunaSA HSM and win2012r2. Then I generated certification request (key pair in HSM), after that i recieved certificate from certification center and performed *"certreq -accept somecert.cer"*
Next, I'm configured IIS for some site, and when i selecting required certificate, i recieving this problem:

[image]

Please advise what can i do in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

My trouble was in Luna KSP configuration
[image]

I registered slot for:

**User: *Administrator* / Domain: *INTEGRATION2***;

**User: *Administrator* / Domain: *NT_AUTHORITY***;

but second string is wrong, it must be:

**User: *SYSTEM* / Domain: *NT_AUTHORITY***;